# Python: How can I gather and parse csv data from a webpage?

Tags: python, csv, cgi, urllib

I have a webpage that prints out csv data using a cgi script. I want to parse the data using Python. So far I know that I can use urllib to request the url and obtain the html into one giant byte string. However, it contains much more than the csv data I need, including html tags, newlines, etc... What I would like to do with this data is to be able to filter rows and columns. This data will eventually go into another csv file which I can use as data to display in graphs (highcharts).

How can I parse the html for just the csv? And is there a library that can gather the csv into a dictionaries or even better, a csv file?

Thanks

Comment: Scrapy maybe http://scrapy.org/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like Scrapy could definitely work. Unfortunately, this will be a lot more work than I imagined to simply filter rows and columns from a webpage :(

Comment: yes, direct DB access would make things much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

1) Use urlib as you metioned

2) Use [Beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for geting a part of document you need

3) Use standard [csv parser](http://pymotw.com/2/csv/) or [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files) to parse data you received at the previous step